# How to append data to the end of a label in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a table view with options of grocery items with price which are stored in a dictionary.

Once user selects a row from table view the item name and price is added to a dictionary and printed in console.

The problem is that i am trying to also display the item name and price in a label for the user to see but i cant seem to get it work because when i iterate for data in items everytime user click on new row the label overwrites instead of appending to new line.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var items : Dictionary<Int, String> = [:]


    @IBOutlet weak var groceryTable: UITableView!{
        didSet {
            groceryTable.dataSource = self
        }
    }

    var groceryData:Dictionary<String, String> = ["Apple":"1", "Kiwi":"2", "Mango":"4", "Broccoli":"3","Milk":"4", "Eggs":"3", "Bread":"6"]


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    //selection of row handler
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Item added!")
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let val = currentCell.textLabel!.text
        items.updateValue(val!, forKey: indexPath.row)
        print(items)


        for data in items{
            let value = data.value
            let line = "\n"
            var a = ""
            a.append(value + line)
            self.label.text=a


        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Item removed!")
        items.removeValue(forKey: indexPath.row)
        print(items)
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groceryData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let key = Array(self.groceryData.keys)[indexPath.row]
        let value = Array(self.groceryData.values)[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = key + ", $"+value
        return cell
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Actual result, label is overwritten with each new click of a row: 
Eggs, $3

Expected: 
Mango, $4
Bread, $6
Eggs, $3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting the answer!

```
for data in items{
            let value = data.value
            label.text = label.text! + value + "\n"
            items.removeValue(forKey: data.key)
        }
```

Comment: in swift it's better to avoid using for loops the Foundation is already enhanced for that to use the new build in functions like `map` / `filter` /`contains` / `allSatisfy` to make your code more compact

Comment: @Sh_Khan And many more such as `reduce`/`forEach`/`compactMap`, etc.

Comment: @George_E it really hard to list them all =D

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
 self.label.text = self.label.text! + items.map { $0.value }.joined(separator:"\n")
```